# Rounding Variable Down

Tags: javascript, variables, rounding

In this script I would like to round Cost6MP after it added 30 percent of itself onto itself so that no decimals will be visible. Is their any way to round this variable(preferably down)?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gainCoinsPS6MP() {
if (Bitcoins > Cost6MP - 1) {
    BitcoinsPS = BitcoinsPS + 1;
    Bitcoins = Bitcoins - Cost6MP;
    Amount6MP = Amount6MP + 1;
    PS6MP = PS6MP + 1;
    Cost6MP = Cost6MP + ((Cost6MP * 30)/100)

} else {
  alert("Are you trying to scam me!?");
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a shot at changing the last line to use [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), it's a like a round down method:

```
Cost6MP = Math.floor(Cost6MP + ((Cost6MP * 30)/100))
```

As the docs show, here is some example effects:

```
console.log(Math.floor(5.95));
// expected output: 5

console.log(Math.floor(5.05));
// expected output: 5

console.log(Math.floor(5));
// expected output: 5

console.log(Math.floor(-5.05));
// expected output: -6
```